# How to select numeric value from longtext field

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to select only the first set of numbers from a longtext column called 'id'.  Here's an example of what the columns contains:

```
:12:;:33:;
:9:;
```

Here's what I want to select:

```
12
9
```

Here's what my select statement would look like if there were no colons or semicolons in the 'id' field:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name='John';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combination of three functions

```
SELECT substring(substring_index(':12:;:33:;', ':',2), instr(':12:;:33:;', ':')+1)
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the `instr` function, when `:` is presumably always the first character.

Comment: i started from that but solved to write more common case

Comment: @shmosel don't delete your answer, OP exactly knows the data structure and will select an answer

Comment: Updated my post with a little more detail, sorry if it wasn't clear.  The 'id' number can be anywhere from 1 to 4 digits.

Comment: your examples have not changed

Comment: No, but I'm trying to match these values based on the "name" column.  Do I just plug in "id" where you have ':12:;:33:;' in your answer?

Comment: Of course. I put string just for example. really should be `SELECT substring(substring_index(id, ':',2), instr(id, ':')+1)`

Comment: @SullyTheUnusual You can accept the answer if you think that it's helpful